# How to show json object in jsp using table tags with ng-repeat directive in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, jsp

```
[Object, "EH882932", "E32", "M42", "873590", 125080, "R0136", "S38", "171", "Arrived ", "Arrived (DLR-DEL)", "3", "XXX", Object, Object, 1392681600000]
```

This is how my json object looks in browser console.Pls help me to show them in jsp using angularjs .The values are dynamic & "object" in json have key , values!

Comment: Is this a list of strings? Can you give a better example of the data including the expanded object

Comment: Thank you for looking at dis !The objects contain {"key":"value","key":"value",...}.the element in the last index is date(1392681600000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ng-repeat I've resolved this issue.Below code works fine when we have key,value pair objects in the data source and both values we want to display.

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in dataSource"> 
<p>{{k}}</p>
<p>{{v}}</p>
</div>
```

If we just want values and keys dont hold any necessity to display then

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataSource"> 
    <p>{{data.key}}</p>
</div>
```